# RegExp pattern for VBA to mark the data into the brackets

Tags: regex, vba, excel

What RegExp pattern I should use to change this one:

`Some text {genome10}Text{/genome10} some text` to this: `Some text, some text`?
Thanx in advance!

Comment: What pattern have you tried so far?

Comment: `{(\w+)}.*?{\/\1}`? if it's supported in VBA?

Comment: I've tried this one: `{([^{]+|)}` - but it check all words/symbols in the brackets.

Comment: `{(.*?)}` almost works - it returns `Some text Text some text` Edit: How about just `{(.*)}`?  It returns `Some text  some text`,  but doesn't have the comma in between...

Comment: @ctweels - {(\w+)}.*?{\/\1} - it is supported, thanx!

Comment: @BruceWayne - {(.*)} - also works, thanx!

Comment: @FL.Alx I would not suggest using `{(.*)}`. It will catch everything between two chunks i.e. `Some text {genome10}Text{/genome10} some text {genome10}Text{/genome10}`. My answer above will catch as few as possible (it's not greedy) since it uses `.*?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this work?

```
Sub simpleRegex()
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "{(.*)}"
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
Dim regEx   As New RegExp
Dim strInput As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("B9")

If strPattern <> "" Then
    strInput = Myrange.Value

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        Debug.Print (WorksheetFunction.Substitute(regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace), "  ", ", "))
    Else
        Debug.Print ("Not matched")
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Note: I used `SUBSTITUTE()` to replace the double space with a `,` to get your example result.

Comment: I should use "CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")" instead of "new regexp" to avoid the error message.

Comment: I've changed the 4th string: `Dim regEx As Object: Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")`

Comment: And it works! - "Some text, some text", thank you, BruceWayne!

Comment: Hi Bruce, I'd suggest changing your regex to the one I put in the comments. This can have unforeseen consequences with strings such as `Some text {genome10}Text{/genome10} some text {genome10}Text{/genome10}`

Comment: But how to check the text only with "genome10" values to leave another tags?

Comment: @FL.Alx do you only want it to work with genome10 or do you want it to work with a potential of others

Comment: How to add to the pattern "genome10" and "/genome10"?

Comment: I'd suggest using `{(genome10)}.*?{\/\1}`

Comment: @ctwheels - I want to check what tags I should delete with a text in it.

Comment: @ctwheels - cool! {(genome10)}.*?{\/\1} - works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: @ctwheels - would you be so kind to help me with a case insensitive pattern? For next cases: {genome10}Text{/genome10}, {Genome10}Text{/Genome10}, {Genome10}Text{/genome10}, {genome10}Text{/Genome10}

Comment: @FL.Alx the easiest way is simply to use the `i` modifier.

Comment: @ctwheels - show me please, where I should use that modifier.

Comment: @FL.Alx See [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options). You want to use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Comment: @ctwheels - I understand, thank you, it works!